# Interpreting the convergence of Taylor series on graph

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Given the function $\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{3}\right)$ and the graph (below), guess an interval of convergence for the Taylor series of the function.

The graph looks as such:

[image: graph of the function]

I'm not sure how to notice where this will converge given this information, I'm sure you can find the exact interval if you have the summation series, but I'm still not good with taking the Ln function and making it a summation to find the exact interval. If you can give me your logical approximation just based off the graph where you think it might converge and why, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a matter of perspective. Adjust the ranges on either axis as needed. Below are two plots using a custom range and the default in Mathematica (which you appear to be using to generate the given plot):

[image]

The logarithm is plotted in blue, and the partial sum (10th in the images above) in orange. Note that the 10th partial sum may not be totally convincing, so feel free to tack on as many as you need to convince yourself. Also note that the logarithm is much more difficult to sort out from the plot on the right, thanks to the default plot range. On the left, the vertical axis ranges from -3 to 3. Tick marks are added at $x=\pm3$ for emphasis. (Code within spoilers)

> `Plot[{Log[1 + x/3], -Sum[(-x/3)^n/n, {n, 1, 10}]}, {x, -20, 20}`

.

> `Plot[{Log[1 + x/3], -Sum[(-x/3)^n/n, {n, 1, 10}]}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, Ticks -> {{-3, 3}, None}]`

Why at $x=\pm3$? Recall that

$$\ln(1+x)=-\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-x)^n}n$$

By the ratio test, one can show that the series converges for

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{(-x)^n}{n}}\right|=|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}=|x|<1$$

Replacing $x$ with $\dfrac x3$, one can establish that

$$\ln\left(1+\frac x3\right)=-\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{\left(-\frac x3\right)^n}n$$

converges for $\left|\dfrac x3\right|<1$, or $|x|<3$, and the image seems to corroborate this at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I think you would do better to zoom a little closer. This graph seems more interesting:

[image]

Comment: Actually Im still confused, because I cut the bounds of my graph on the x-axis from (-6,0) and now it looks like the graph converges around -6 but from my zoomed out version it seems as if it would go to -17 or so